# How do I return to the modeling view from the node view?

Tags: interface

I don't even know how this happened but my modeling view only displays my nodes and I can't find the button to return to modeling.[image]

Comment: Your image shows that you are in the Shader Editor. Can't you just click on that icon, the one to the left of where it shows that you are in Object Mode, and change to the 3D Viewport?

Comment: Probably you pressed `Ctrl`+`Spacebar` to maximize the current window you're in. To get back just press it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get back to 3D-View.

1. Press Ctrl + Spacebar to reverse maximizing the current window. If that didn't do the trick, reverse this by pressing the shortcut a second time.
2. You can go to the button with the circle icon right next to the "Object" button. Click it. Now there should be a list of windows you can navigate to. Click on 3D-View and you are back. 
   Alternatively, press Shift + F5 to do that.
3. You can just create a new "Modeling" window on the top. Press the small "+" button next to "Scripting" and navigate to "General>Modeling", click that and then delete the old "Modeling" window by right clicking the tab and pressing "Delete".
4. You can revert your window back to factory settings. Go to "File>Defaults>Load Factory Settings". Remember to save your work before you do that.